# Why $y=f(2x-6)$ is a 3 unit rightward shift of $y=f(2x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**$2.2.4$:**
Suppose that $f(4)=8$. Note that the point $(2,8)$ is on the graph of $y=f(2x)$ and that the point $(5,8)$ is on the graph of $y=f(2x-6)$. So, the point we have found on the graph of $y=f(2x-6)$ is $3$ units to the right of the point we found on the graph of $y=f(2x)$. Which of the following is true:

1. We made a mistake
2. It's a coincidence
3. The graph of $y=f(2x-6)$ is a $3$ unit rightward shift of $y=f(2x)$

Explain your answer.

---

I know that $3$ is correct, but I just don't know how to prove it. I believe that it has something to do with this concept called a horizontal shift, where we have the form $y=f(\frac 1a(x+b))$, but we haven't learned about horizontal shifts yet.

Comment: I suggest you take a few examples, like $f(x)=x$, $f(x)=x^2$ etc. and convince yourself of $3$ first. Once you're done with this, you can see how  these transformations behave by seeing the examples themselves.The proof is rather elementary once you have understood the transformation, but that is why I suggest you take these examples.

Comment: Suppose that $f$ is invertable. Solve for $x$. $f^{-1}(y) = f^{-1}(f(2x-6))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it is $f[2(x-3)]$, Let's call this function $g$.

Notice how $g(3)=f(2\times 0)=f[2\times (3-3)],\\ g(4)=f(2\times 1)=f[2\times(4-3)],\\ g(5)=f(2\times 2)=f[2\times(5-3)],$

and so on...
That is, for every $t$ we will plug into $g$, we get the same value we get by plugging $t-3$ into $f(2x)$ (easy to prove for all $t$). It therefore means that the whole graph is shifted 3 units right.

I would play a bit more with function graphers to get the drift if you still didn't get the idea. I doubt there's a better way to explain it but I might be wrong.